# How to display 'processing..' message to user while the Bot is doing work behind the scenes

Tags: botframework

I want to display a processing message to the user while the Bot is performing some heavy data retrieval task.

```
var leadRetrievalTask = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            msg = LeadsManager.getTopLeads(authRes);
        });

        await context.PostAsync("Retrieving Top Leads data..."); //should display processing message`enter code here`
        await leadRetrievalTask; 
        await context.PostAsync(msg); //should display result
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
```

But both the message and results are getting displayed together. Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

We don't have yet, but are planning (for channels that support it) support for the "Typing..." message some channels support.

How long is the task?  Are you saying they're not posting separately?

Comment: the data collation is now taking arnd 30secs-50secs, but would be good if we show some message to the user while the retrieval is happening. Currently I am using the flow as shown in the code snippet , but both the processing and results appear together.